# Pyaudio Installation failure on Ubuntu

Tags: python, pyaudio

Pyaudio Installation failure on Ubuntu
I have ubuntu 18LTS
python 2 and python 3
pip 10

I installed libportaudio2     and libasound-dev from suggestions I found on google. Is it because I need to install other libraries as well?

Here is the error I got 
I tried the sudo -H flag but no difference.

```
sudo python -m pip install pyaudio
The directory '/home/ec2/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/ec2/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting pyaudio
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-wGfA8D/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-IYb2Y1/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-nbjU53/python2.7-2.7.15~rc1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/_portaudiomodule.o
    src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:10: fatal error: portaudio.h: No such file or directory
     #include "portaudio.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-wGfA8D/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-IYb2Y1/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-wGfA8D/pyaudio/
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> fatal error: portaudio.h: No such file or directory

you are missing some build dependencies, so it fails compilation. specifically, the error shows it can't find `portaudio.h`, which comes with the `portaudio19-dev` package.

so install the required headers with:

```
sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev
```

then try your pip install.

Answer (score 7):

You can try

```
sudo apt-get install python-pyaudio
```

Try this before installing the package:

```
sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev
```

If the above suggestion doesn't work:

```
sudo apt-get install libjack-jackd2-dev portaudio19-dev
```

and `pip install pyaudio` should work.